# In App Purchase with Student Discount

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, discounts

I'm working on an iPhone app that unlocks further content through an in app purchase. However, I'd like the ability to offer a student discount for the upgrade. I tried creating a second in app purchase at the discounted price, that you could download from the app after entering a "student code". Apple rejected this as it violates 11.1 of the app store review guidelines. I think they are treating this more like we are selling student codes somewhere and this is outside the in app purchasing.

Is there no way to offer a student discount rate?

Comment: This question is not programming related, but I'd recommend contacting Apple and explaining the situation to them.

Comment: Also, this question might be much better off on [the App Stores proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not allow the student discount on any of the App Stores. With the current App Store submission guidelines, you will not be able to offer a student discount.

[Apple App Store Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)

Comment: Thanks Bill. I've submitted an appeal to see if apple has any suggestions.